# View.GONE alternative in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'll give an example of the problem, let's say I have two buttons within the Box

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun testView() {
    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .size(200.dp)
    ) {
        Button(onClick = {
            Log.e("HERE", "First btn")
        }) {
            Text(text = "Btn1")
        }

        Button(modifier = Modifier
            onClick = {
            Log.e("HERE", "Second btn")
        }) {
            Text(text = "Btn2")
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the app I see `Btn2` (which is actually on the top of the `Btn1`) and when I click in the log I see `Second btn` as expected.

Let's say I need to hide `Btn2` so the user can click `Btn1`, in order to do this in old way I would add `View.GONE` and it would work, however in JetpackCompose (as far as I understood) there is only `alpha` option, so I try to set it to `0f` like this

```
...
Button(modifier = Modifier
            .alpha(0f),
            onClick = {
            Log.e("HERE", "Second btn")
        }) {
            Text(text = "Btn2")
        }
...
```

When I run the app I see (as expected) `Btn1` on the screen, however, when I click I see in the log `Second btn`.

So, it is obvious that `alpha` is changing the visibility but the view itself is still there.

The question is there an alternative for `View.GONE` as it was before?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way to do that would be not to output the second button if you would want it GONE.

```
if( some_condition) {
    Button(modifier = Modifier
        onClick = {
        Log.e("HERE", "Second btn")
    }) {
        Text(text = "Btn2")
    }
}
```

If some_condition is false, it won't output the Button, and it won't appear.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create an object that triggers recomposition,Recomposition is triggered when state changes.

```
var isSplash by mutableStateOf(true)
if (isSplash) {
    SplashView()
    isSplash = false
} else {
    Main()
    //...
}
```

Comment: I guess you mean "recomposition" instead of "recombination".

Comment: yes！thank you for reminding me,modified @Bennik2000